# etcd api on CoreOS - setting ip address configurations remotely

Tags: docker, coreos, etcd

I am attempting to use etcd's remote api to configure a coreOS box remotely with static values like ip address, dns resolve address, gateway, ect.

I theory I should be able to file something like:

curl -X PUT "[http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:4001/v2/keys/*etcd/registry/*???_/_state?prevExist=false](http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:4001/v2/keys/_etcd/registry/_???_/_state?prevExist=false)" -d value=10.10.10.1

But i can't find a reference to the exact syntax to use.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to accomplish if not just setting arbitrary keys? Are you trying to actually configure the CoreOS host settings through etcd?

Comment: I'm attempting to setup the actual host configurations of the CoreOS host settings.

Comment: I don't think etcd handles any of that. It is just a key value store. I'll add an actual answer with some more context and you can comment on it if I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

etcd doesn't handle configuration of the host system. It is a distributed key / value store. It can certainly store configuration for applications and maybe even the host. But you have need some other tool to pull the data from the store and transform it into configuration that the application or host recognizes. The application I use to do this inside Docker containers is confd (https://github.com/kelseyhightower/confd).

For configuration of the CoreOS host, you would generally be using Cloud-Config (https://coreos.com/docs/cluster-management/setup/cloudinit-cloud-config/) and writing unit files to deal with certain parts of the system, such as networking (https://coreos.com/docs/cluster-management/setup/network-config-with-networkd/). Hope this helps!